# How to create format rule to get no space before opening brace?

Tags: c++, c, clang-format

I am trying to use clang format to automatically format my code.
But there seems to be no option to configure the positon of the opening Brace.

The option *BreakBeforeBraces* can be used to put the Brace on the next line,
but no option to disable the leading space.

I am using clang-format 8.0.0.
The [documentation](http://releases.llvm.org/8.0.0/tools/clang/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html) does not seem to contain any info on this.

This is how clang formats code:

```
class test {

};

int main() {
    if() {
        // Here the Space before the if can be configured with:
        // SpaceBeforeParens: SBPO_Never
    }
}
```

This is how I would like it to look:

```
class test{

};

int main(){
    if(){
        // stuff
    }
}
```

Is this possible with clang-format ?

Comment: But it looks so much better with the space!

Comment: I guess that's personal preference

Comment: It might just not be in there if it's not a recognized code style. I tend to see styles adding more types of white space in that gap, not removing it.

Comment: It might be that no one came up with this awful style before, hence the lack of support.

Comment: To get that format, you'll probably need to find an alternative code formatter.  There are many to choose from.  If the one you like doesn't do what you want, you either suck it up and accept the wisdom of those who wrote it, or you switch to one that does what you want, or you modify the source for the Clang formatter so that it can be configured to do what you want, and then you try to persuade the powers that be that this is a legitimate requirement and that your code is a legitimate solution and that they should accept the change into the code base.  I suspect it may not be accepted.

Comment: @peterzuger: Have you got this one working?

Comment: @Jenny: No so far I have not found anything, I just have a regexp ready to replace all ") {" with "){" and a few others. All code formater's that I have found do not support this

Comment: @peterzuger just here to say I prefer your way of formatting as well.